# Postfix. Sending some messages using external smtp server and some messages "directly". Issue with sender_dependent_relayhost_maps

Tags: email, postfix, smtp, mandrill

I'm configuring a new web server and i need to make emails from my PHP scripts to be sent.  Most messages should be sent using mandrill SMTP and some "directly" from my server to email services.  I registered an account at mandrill and configured postfix server according to [this](https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582187-How-to-Use-Postfix-to-Send-Email-with-Mandrill) tutorial.   I created /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd and edited main.cf file. I set relayhost to mandrill SMTP.

> relayhost = [smtp.mandrillapp.com]

If i try sending messages when postfix configured this way -  all messages being sent using mandrill SMTP. I tried it and it works. But as i said, i need some messages to be sent directly. I determine, which emails should be sent using SMTP and which directly, by setting different sender("from") email addresses. 
In the tutorial i mentioned i found that to do what i need, i need to use sender_dependent_relayhost_maps option and remove the value of relayhost.
I use the following config

> relayhost =
>   sender_dependent_relayhost_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/relayhost_maps

I created /etc/postfix/relayhost_maps and it looks like this

> mail@mydomain.com    [smtp.mandrillapp.com]

Now all messages should be sent directly, except for messages from mail@mydomain.com that must be sent using external SMTP.
The problem is  when i try to send messages with this configuration - **all** messages being sent directly(i see this in gmail when i receive it).

I tried putting in /etc/postfix/relayhost_maps different SMTP hosts, different email addresses but all messages still being sent directly.

Please, help me solve this problem.